# Burninate the [odb2] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are currently 12 questions using the [odb2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odb2) tag that are all asking about fault codes. It seems this tag should be removed and all references to it updated to use the [obd-ii](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obd-ii) tag instead.

I'm not familiar with this process, so I don't know if I should go through and update the questions manually, or if there is more to it than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly as you stated, which made a lot of sense. [obd2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obd2) -> [obd-ii](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obd-ii) with a synonym made so as it won't happen again. Thanks for bringing this to light.